# Method of Partial Fractions integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{dx}{x^4+3x^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x^2(x^2+3)} = A(x^2+3) + (Bx+C)x^2 = \frac{A}{x^2} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3} = Ax^2 + 3A + Bx^2 + Cx^2$

I am having some trouble solving the system of equations that follows. I tried plugging into my calculator a 4x4 matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ but the RREF form only gave me $A,B,C = 0$ which doesn't seem like the right answer and I am now stuck.

I would prefer hints rather than answers at this time!

---

**Edit:**

My initial partial fractions was incomplete. The correct one is posted below:

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+3}
= A(x)(x^2+3) + B(x^2+3) + (Cx+D)x^2$$

$$ = Ax^3 + 3Ax + Bx^2 + 3B + Cx^3 + Dx^2 $$

This gives me the following matrix:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ but the RREF is still giving me $A,B,C,D = 0$!

---

**Edit:**
attempting to solve system of equations...

$1 = Ax(x^2+3) + B(x^2+3) + Cx^3 + Dx^2$
Let x = 1,

1 = A(4) + B(4) + C + D

???

Comment: You have a product of two quadratics in the denominator with no linear term. Make the substitution $x^2=y$ (only to find the partial fraction decomposition and not for integration). The integrand becomes $\frac1{y(y+3)}$ which is a product of linear terms and can be easily decomposed into $\frac13\big[\frac1y-\frac1{y+3}\big]=\frac13\big[\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2+3}\big]$

Comment: Wow, we've got the equal-isn't-equal-to-equal-unless-when-it-is-equal-to-equal kind of equal in the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For partial fractions involving denominators of perfect powers, you need to split it up in a slightly different way:

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+3}$$

**Edit**: in this specific case, we can get the equality $$1 = Ax(x^2+3) + B(x^2+3) + Cx^3 + Dx^2$$

From this we can obtain a set of simultaneous equations by substituting $x = 0,1,-1,2$ to get:

$$ 1 = 3B $$
$$ 1 = 4A+4B+C+D $$
$$ 1 = -4A+4B-C+D $$
$$ 1 = 14A+7B+8C+4D $$

You can solve this with any method you like (e.g. RREF).

**Double edit**: I've just worked out the way you were taught to do it, by comparing coefficients rather than making substitutions. This works too. The issue is simply in your matrix: you have that you want $Ax^3 + 3Ax + Bx^2 + 3B + Cx^3 + Dx^2$ to be equal to $1$ (the numerator of the original fraction). This is why it's important to take care of where you use equality signs: your string of equalities in the original post are not correct. Your matrix should be

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Note the $1$ in the bottom right corresponding to the $1$ in the numerator of the initial fraction. Solving this will give you $A=C=0$, $B=1/3$, $D=-1/3$, which is correct. And then you can integrate.

Comment: Oh, yes you are totally right. However that didn't seem to change my system of equations outcome still. Please see my edits above

Comment: I'm not familiar with the matrix way of doing this. Here's how I learned it: we know $\frac{1}{x^2(x^2+3)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+3}$ so multiply upwards by $x^2(x^2+3)$ and you get that $1 = Ax(x^2+3) + B(x^2+3) + Cx^3 + Dx^2$. Then by putting $x=0,1,-1,2$ or any other convenient values, you get simultaneous equations which should yield $A=C=0$, $B=1/3$, $D=-1/3$.

Comment: How are you isolating A,B, and C to solve for them? Is there a more details you can provide or some additional resources?

Comment: please see my new edit, I don't think I understand how to solve the system of equations after letting $x=1$ and how to "get the simultaneous equations" (not sure why you call it simultaneous equations)

Comment: See my edit. Do what you did but not just for $x=1$; also for $x=0$, $x=-1$ and $x=2$. The values of $x$ chosen are arbitrary - the point is that with each substitution you get a new equation, and for four unknowns you need four equations.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Even in the revised decomposition equation in the question, there is an error: The denominator is missing on the right-hand side: We should have 
$$\frac{1}{x^2 (x^2 + 3)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+3} .$$

**Hint** Before proceeding with cross-multiplication or substitution, we can simplify the resulting linear algebra by observing that the rational function that we are decomposing (on the left-hand side) is even, hence the right-hand side must be too. This immediately forces
$$A = C = 0 .$$
(To see this, recall that since an even function is unchanged by the replacement $x \mapsto -x$, applying that substitution to the right-hand side and comparing with the original equation gives those values.)

With this in hand, the decomposition equation simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{x^2 (x^2 + 3)} = \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{D}{x^2+3}. $$

> Cross-multiplying gives $$1 = B(x^2 + 3) + D(x^2) = (B + D)x^2 + 3 B,$$ comparing the constant coefficients gives $3B = 1$, so $B = \frac{1}{3}$, and then comparing the remaining coefficients gives $B + D = 0$, so $D = -B = -\frac{1}{3}$.